# Selecting only attributes specified using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

This is a working code made using exporting the script from ModelBuilder.

```
import arcpy

# Local variables:
Links_Final = "Links_Final"
condition = "\"RR1\"= 777 OR \"RR2\"=777 OR \"RR3\"=777 OR \"RR4\"=777"

# Process: Select Layer By Attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Links_Final, "NEW_SELECTION", condition)
```

However, the I want the value **777** in the **condition** to be taken from the user. So I added this code.

```
value = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)) 
condition = "\"RR1\"= value OR \"RR2\"= value OR \"RR3\"= value OR \"RR4\"= value"
```

Now the code throws an error saying, **Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)**

I have also followed the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483187/trying-to-create-a-simple-select-by-attribute-script-based-on-an-input but that does not work either.

Note: My data type on the field is long integer and the data type taken from the user (as specified while creating the script) was long (as I could not find int type there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [python String Format](https://pyformat.info/) to pass parameters into a string variable.  Also triple quote your string so that you don't have to escape each internal quote mark.

```
import arcpy

# Local variables:
Links_Final = "Links_Final"
value = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)) 

condition = """ "RR1" = {0} OR "RR2" = {0} OR "RR3" = {0} OR "RR4" = {0} """.format(value)

# Process: Select Layer By Attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Links_Final, "NEW_SELECTION", condition)
```